# Sinon.js - stub React component's function before component is instantiated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon

Let's say I have a component that looks like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
    test : function () {
        return true;
    },
    render : function () {
        var test = this.test();
        return (
            <div className="test-component">
                Test component - {test}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ExampleComponent;
```

In my test, I could render this component using `TestUtils`, then stub out the method like so:

```
var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ExampleComponent/>);
sinon.stub(renderedComponent, 'test').returns(false);
expect(renderedComponent.test).toBe(false); //passes
```

But is there a way I could tell Sinon to automatically stub out a component's function every time an instance of that component is created?  Ex:

```
sinon.stubAll(ExampleComponent, 'test').returns(false); //something like this
var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ExampleComponent/>);
expect(renderedComponent.test).toBe(false); //I'd like this to pass
```

If this isn't possible, is there a potential solution that comes close to providing the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

To clarify, my problem is that I wanted to stub out functions that belong to children components that are rendered under a parent component.  So something like this:

**parent.js**

```
var Child = require('./child.js');
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <Child/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Parent;
```

**child.js**

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    test : function () {
        return true;
    },
    render : function () {
        if (this.test) {
            throw('boom');
        }
        return (
            <div className="child">
                Child
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Child;
```

If I were to use TestUtils to render Parent in one of my tests, it would throw the error, which I wanted to avoid.  So my problem was that I needed to stub out Child's `test` function before it was instantiated.  Then, when I render Parent, Child won't blow up.

The answer provided did not quite work, as Parent uses `require()` to get Child's constructor.  I'm not sure why, but because of that, I can't stub out Child's prototype in my test and expect the test to pass, like so:

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils,
    Parent = require('./parent.js'),
    Child = require('./child.js'),
    sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Parent', function () {
    it('does not blow up when rendering', function () {
        sinon.stub(Child.prototype, 'test').returns(false);
        var parentInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Parent/>); //blows up
        expect(parentInstance).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

I was able to find a solution that fit my needs though.  I switched my testing framework from Mocha to Jasmine, and I started using [jasmine-react](https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react), which provided several benefits, including the ability to stub out a function of a class before it is instantiated.  Here is an example of a working solution:

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    Parent = require('./parent.js'),
    Child = require('./child.js'),
    jasmineReact = require('jasmine-react-helpers');

describe('Parent', function () {
    it('does not blow up when rendering', function () {
        jasmineReact.spyOnClass(Child, 'test').and.returnValue(false);
        var parentInstance = jasmineReact.render(<Parent/>, document.body); //does not blow up
        expect(parentInstance).toBeTruthy(); //passes
    });
});
```

I hope this helps someone else with a similar issue.  If anyone has any questions I would be glad to help.

Answer (score 16):

You will need to overwrite the `ExampleComponent.prototype` instead of `ExampleComponent`. `ExampleComponent` is a constructor. Local methods like `test()` are saved in it's `prototype`.

```
sinon.stub(ExampleComponent.prototype, 'test').returns(false);
var renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ExampleComponent/>);
expect(renderedComponent.test).toBe(false); //passes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  While it seems to work for some cases, it does not quite do what I am looking for.  I probably should have been a bit more specific.  I have a parent and a child component, and the child component is rendered inside of the parent component's `render` method.  The parent uses `require()` to get the constructor, and there doesn't seem to be a way to override the child's prototype inside my test.  Does this make sense?  I can update my question with an example if you would like.

Comment: It would be great if you could extend the question with an example.

Comment: I found a working solution, but I will still award you the bounty.